# a-marker-camera in barcode mode in ar.js

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

I'm new to both ar.js and a-frame. I've got a tutorial working that does almost what I want. As the next step I'd like to anchor my entire scene to the marker, but just can't get it to work.
Here's what works, a translucent cube hovers over the #5 barcode marker when I point my phone camera at it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <a-scene embedded arjs="detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;">
            <a-marker type="barcode" value="5">
                <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="opacity: 0.9;"></a-box>        
            </a-marker>
            <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I'd like to do, but does not work (the box does not show up):

```
    <a-scene embedded arjs="detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;">
         <a-marker-camera type="barcode" value="5"></a-marker-camera>
         <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="opacity: 0.9;"></a-box>        
    </a-scene>
```

I can make it work by switching to a different marker type, but I'd like to stick with the barcode for performance (even though I'm only planning to use a single marker):

```
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
        <a-marker-camera preset="hiro"></a-marker-camera>
        <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="opacity: 0.9;"></a-box>        
    </a-scene>
```

So my question is: Can I use a-marker-camera with a barcode style marker? If yes, then how? And what am I doing wrong? TIA!